# JavaScript Forms - Applying a Discount for a Certain Quantity

Tags: javascript, forms, variables

I am creating a simple form that calculates price based on quantity ordered and tax. I also want to apply a discount for the following quantities:

10-19: 10% discount
20-29: 20% discount
30-39: 30 % discount
40-99: 40 % discount

My issue is that the function still returns the total price without the discount for a certain quantity. When the quantity entered is in a certain range, I have set it up so that the discount updates to the appropriate percentage (var discountPrice). If a discount is applied, then the total should update to the discountedTotal, and calculate the tax and final total from there. However, there seems to be an issue with my syntax since none of this is being applied to the function when I run it.

Any insight as to why the if/else statement or the function as a whole is not running properly would be appreciated. If needed, here is the full HTML/JS: http://jsfiddle.net/pas0tmpL/

```
function priceCalculation() {

var nameFirst = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
var nameLast = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
var phoneNum = document.getElementById("phone_number").value;
var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity_order").value;
var price = document.getElementById("price_fixed").value;
var total = quantity * price;
var discountPrice = 0
var discountedTotal = total - (total * discountPrice);
const taxRate = 0.085;
var tax = total * taxRate;
var totalPlusTax = total + tax;

if (quantity > 9 || quantity < 20) {
        discountPrice = .10;        
        total = discountedTotal;
    }           
    else if (quantity > 19 || quantity < 30) {
        discountPrice = .20;
        total = discountedTotal;
    }
    else if (quantity > 29 || quantity < 40) {
        discountPrice = .30;
        total = discountedTotal;    
    }
    else if (quantity > 39 || quantity < 100) {
        discountPrice = .40;
        total = discountedTotal;    
    }

document.getElementById("order_total").value = "$" + totalPlusTax.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the prices to be calculated in the client side?

Comment: bit unrelated to question, but `const` won't work in many browsers, as it's a part of ES6 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: I highly suggest that you provide the price calculated from server side. The client can manipulate the value of  the var "Price". If you want just to implement this in order to provide a good experience to your customer then it's OK, however you will need to change your code twice if you change your logic.

Comment: @Othman Given that the jsfiddle tries to include a (non-existent) javascript called "Lesson7_JavaScript" I think it's safe to assume this is homework, and the code will never be seen by a real customer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
function priceCalculation() {
var nameFirst = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
var nameLast = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
var phoneNum = document.getElementById("phone_number").value;
var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity_order").value;    
var price = document.getElementById("price_fixed").value;
var total = quantity * price;
var discountPrice = 0  ;
var discountedTotal = 0;
const taxRate = 0.085;
var tax = total * taxRate;
var totalPlusTax = total + tax;

   if (quantity > 9 || quantity < 20) {
        discountPrice = .10;        
        total = total - (total * discountPrice);
    }           
    else if (quantity > 19 || quantity < 30) {
        discountPrice = .20;
        total = total - (total * discountPrice);
    }
    else if (quantity > 29 || quantity < 40) {
        discountPrice = .30;
        total = total - (total * discountPrice);    
    }
    else if (quantity > 39 || quantity < 100) {
        discountPrice = .40;
        total = total - (total * discountPrice);    
    }

document.getElementById("order_total").value = "$" + totalPlusTax.toFixed(2);

} // end function priceCalculation();
```

Comment: This only solves one of the many problems in the code.  And I'm surprised you can get away with the missing semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems that I can see.  One is, you calculate the `discountedTotal` at the beginning using

```
var discountPrice = 0
var discountedTotal = total - (total * discountPrice);
```

total - (total * 0) will just give you `total`.  You should probably only set `discountedTotal` after you know what your `discountPrice` is...

Your if statements have some problems also.  As a hint, `||` means "or".  Thus your first if is saying "if the quantity is more than 9 or less than 20"--and every integer in existence is either more than 9 or less than 20 (some are both!).  So you'll only ever attempt to apply the first discount, and that to everything.

Good luck!